# Kubectl insufficient resource allocation in aws cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, kubernetes, kubectl

I am new to Kubernetes and I am facing a problem that I do not understand. I created a 4-node cluster in aws, 1 manager node (t2.medium) and 3 normal nodes (c4.xlarge) and they were successfully joined together using Kubeadm.

Then I tried to deploy three Cassandra replicas using [this yaml](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/blob/master/cassandra/cassandra-statefulset.yaml) but the pod state does not leave the pending state; when I do:

```
kubectl describe pods cassandra-0
```

I get the message

```
0/4 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate, 3 Insufficient memory.
```

And I do not understand why, as the machines should be powerful enough to cope with these pods and I haven't deployed any other pods. I am not sure if this means anything but when I execute:

```
kubectl describe nodes
```

I see this message:

```
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
```

Therefore my question is why this is happening and how can I fix it.

Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 3):

Each node tracks the total amount of requested RAM (`resources.requests.memory`) for all pods assigned to it. That cannot exceed the total capacity of the machine. I would triple check that you have no other pods. You should see them on `kubectl describe node`.